# Prepend character to each value in a delimited string

Tags: php, prefix, delimited

I am trying to take a string like `php,mysql,css`
and turn it into `#php #mysql #css`

What I have so far:

```
$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTags = explode(",", $hashTagStr);

foreach($hashTags as $k => $v){
    $hashTagsStr = '';
    $hashTagsStr .= '#'.$v.' ';
}
echo $hashTagsStr;
```

Problem is it only prints `#css`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTags = explode(",", $hashTagStr);
$hashTagStr = '#' . implode( ' #', $hashTags );
```

...or:

```
$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTagStr = '#' . str_replace( ',', ' #', $hashTagStr );
```

Answer (score 6):

That's because every time the loop runs you're clearing out $hashTagsStr by doing:

```
$hashTagsStr = '';
```

Change it to:

```
$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTags = explode(",", $hashTagStr);
$hashTagsStr = '';
foreach($hashTags as $k => $v){
    $hashTagsStr .= '#'.$v.' ';
}
echo $hashTagsStr;
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass your values by reference:

```
$hashTags = array("php","mysql","css");

foreach ( $hashTags as &$v ) $v = "#" . $v;
```

Then hammer out the results:

```
// #php #mysql #css
echo implode( " ", $hashTags );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/zbtLF5Pk

Let's examine what you're doing:

```
// You start with a string, all good.
$hashTagStr = "php,mysql,css";

// Blow it apart into an array - awesome!
$hashTags = explode( "," , $hashTagStr );

// Yeah, let's cycle this badboy!
foreach($hashTags as $k => $v) {

    // Iteration 1: Yeah, empty strings!
    // Iteration 2: Yeah, empty...wait, OMG!
    $hashTagsStr = '';

    // Concat onto an empty var
    $hashTagsStr .= '#'.$v.' ';
}

// Show our final output
echo $hashTagsStr;
```

Answer (score 3):

looks like a Job for `array_walk`

```
$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTags = explode(",", $hashTagStr);
array_walk($hashTags, function(&$value){ $value = "#" . $value ;} );
var_dump(implode(" ", $hashTags));
```

Output

```
 string '#php #mysql #css' (length=16)
```

Comment: You can also use `array_map`. `$hashTags = array_map(function($a){return "#$a";}, $hashTags);` :-P

Answer (score 2):

You should move the `$hashTagsStr = ''` line outsite the foreach loop, otherwise you reset it each time

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the variable `$hashTagsStr`inside the loop.

```
<?php

$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTags = explode(",", $hashTagStr);

$hashTagsStr = '';
foreach($hashTags as $k => $v){
    $hashTagsStr .= '#'.$v.' ';
}
echo $hashTagsStr;
```

Anyway, I think this would be simpler:

```
<?php

$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTagStr = '#' . str_replace(',', ' #', $hashTagStr);

echo $hashTagStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

During each iteration of the loop, you are doing `$hashTagsStr = '';`.  This is setting the variable to `''`, and then appending the current tag.  So, when it's done, `$hashTagsStr` will only contain the last tag.

Also, a loop seems like too much work here, you can much easier just replace the `,` with `#`.  No need to break it into an aray, no need to loop.  Try this:

```
$hashTagStr  = "php,mysql,css";
$hashTagStr = '#'.str_replace(',', ' #', $hashTagStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function prepend( $pre, $array )
{
    return array_map(
        function($t) use ($pre) { return $pre.$t; }, $array
    );
}
```

What you *semantically* have in your string is an array. ➪ So better explode as soon as possible, and keep working with your array, as long as possible.

[Closures & anonymous functions](http://dhorrigan.com/post/29209695084/anonymous-functions-vs-closures) as shown work in PHP 5.4+.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to implement a solution that will not prepend `#` to an empty array. A good general solution should also not create an unnecessary trailing space.  Ideally, a robust generalized solution should work regardless of the delimited value characters.

This will never generate any unwanted characters.  Split the values by delimiter, prepend `#` to each value with `substr_replace(), then re-join with spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LR7H0))

```
echo implode(
         ' ',
         substr_replace(
             explode(',', $hashTagStr),
             '#',
             0,
             0
         )
     );
```